# Use u16 as the type of capacity and len of Vec

Tags: rust

I have a 2D Vec<Vec>, the inner vec has only < 655336 len, and the out Vec has > 1G len, so I want the type of capacity and len of the inner vec are u16 instead of usize, which can save memory.

Here is a demo C code:

```
typedef struct {
    u16 len;
    u16 capacity;
    u8 *vec;
} vec;
```

How can I translate this c code to rust code and use the same memory layout?

Comment: First, don't do that. Second read [The Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html).

Comment: If you just want to enforce that a user doesn't try to access invalid space, you should create an opaque wrapper class that forces getter/setter methods to handle bounds-checking.

Comment: I agree with @AleksanderKrauze, don't do that. You *very very likely* won't even notice the difference, and there are *most likely* other things you can optimize more easily with a greater impact.